# Search and replace backslash except one thing

Tags: bash, backslash

I want to replace `\` with `\\` except `\N`.
So I got so far

```
sed ‘s/\\/\\\\/g’
```

But I’m not sure how to add ignore

Sample:

```
aa  \N  aa
\N  aa  aa
aa  aa  \N
\N  \N  aa
\N  aa  \N
aa  \N  \N
\N  \N  \N
aa  aa  aa
\N  bb  \N
\       aa
```

should be:

```
aa  \N  aa
\N  aa  aa
aa  aa  \N
\N  \N  aa
\N  aa  \N
aa  \N  \N
\N  \N  \N
aa  aa  aa
\N  bb  \N
\\      aa
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```bash
echo '\ \\ \N \\N' |
sed -E 's/\\(N)|(\\)/\\\1\2/g'
```

```
\\ \\\\ \N \\\N
```

Comment: works! how's the performance of this (on million of rows)

Comment: The performance should be alright

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `'s/\/\([^N]\)/\/\/\1/'`

Simple match `/` and the character after, requiring to not match `N` character.

The matched character (other from `N`) will be stroed in captureing group and can be used in replacement with `\1` :)

Results from sed.js.org:

[image]

Comment: Does not work on the above sample. tried `sed 's/\/\([^N]\)/\/\/\1/g'`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is a way to say: *I want to match a pattern that is not followed by something*.

As far as I know, `sed` does not support lookarounds, but you can keep most of your syntax with this `perl` command:

```
perl -pe 's/\\(?!N)/\\\\/g'
```